# Erro: The constructor VelocityTemplate(InputStream) is undefined

Tags: java, java-ee, cdi

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool;

import com.outjected.email.impl.templating.velocity.VelocityTemplate;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EnvioPedidoEmailBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Mailer mailer;

@Inject
@PedidoEdicao
private Pedido pedido;

public void enviarPedido() {
    MailMessage message = mailer.novaMensagem();

    message.to(this.pedido.getCliente().getEmail())
        .subject("Pedido " + this.pedido.getId())
        .bodyHtml(new VelocityTemplate(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emails/pedido.template")))
        .put("pedido", this.pedido)
        .put("numberTool", new NumberTool())
        .put("locale", new Locale("pt", "BR"))
        .send();
```

Dependencia

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Esse erro continua mesmo com alteração da versão da dependencia...
Erro na linha 37:

```
.bodyHtml(new 
VelocityTemplate(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emails/pedido.template")))
```

Comment: Essa classe `MailMessage` vem de qual biblioteca?

Comment: import com.outjected.email.api.MailMessage;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade eu substituí a linha:

```
.bodyHtml(new VelocityTemplate(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emails/apontamento.template")))
```

Por:

```
.bodyHtml(new VelocityTemplate(new File("/emails/apontamento.template")))
```

E funcionou...